# Why is my Blazor file upload returning null when handling image uploads?

Tags: c#, file-upload, blazor, blazor-server-side, razor-pages

I'm encountering an issue with file uploads in my Blazor application. When I attempt to upload an image file, the value I receive in my HandleImageUpload method appears to be null, resulting in errors further in my code.

```
<div class="form-group">
                <label for="createProductImage">Upload Image</label>
                <input id="createProductImage" type="file" accept="image/*" @onchange="HandleImageUpload" />
            </div>
```

Here's my code for handling file uploads:

```
private async Task HandleImageUpload(ChangeEventArgs e)
{
    var fileList = e.Value as IEnumerable<IBrowserFile>;
    if (fileList == null || !fileList.Any()) return;

    var imageFile = fileList.First();

    // Convert IBrowserFile to IFormFile
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        await imageFile.OpenReadStream().CopyToAsync(stream);
        selectedImageFile = new FormFile(stream, 0, stream.Length, null!, Path.GetFileName(imageFile.Name));
    }
}
```

However, fileList is null, and I'm not sure why this is happening. When I check the value of e.Value, it contains the file location (e.g., "C:\fakepath\bag.jpg"). I expect to receive a valid list of browser files.

I'm using a Blazor Server application, and I've included the necessary using directives and dependencies for handling file uploads. Can someone help me understand why I'm getting a null value for fileList and how I can correctly handle file uploads in Blazor?
The issue occurs when I attempt to convert IBrowserFile to IFormFile in the HandleImageUpload method.

Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: You should use <InputFile /> Component and InputFileChangeEventArgs

Comment: My own image upload code uses `<InputFile>`, which may be telling as I almost always prefer vanilla HTML inputs over the Blazor component equivalents.

Comment: @Xserge I tried using `<InputFile />` but it is still not working

Comment: Don't need to convert to FormFile-- that looks sus to me.  You can open a read stream directly on  the IBrowserFile, and copy it directly to a filestream (i.e. your save file): `await imageFile.OpenReadStream(100 * 1024 * 1024).CopyToAsync(fileStream);`  The numeric variable is the max file size-- I set mine to 100MB because quite a lot of licensable images are 50MB+.

Answer (score 0):

You may follow the sample in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-8.0#server-side-file-upload-example):

```
<InputFile OnChange="@HandleImageUpload" multiple />
.....

@code {
  ......

 private async Task HandleImageUpload(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
    {

        var files = e.GetMultipleFiles();
   }

}
```